# Interleaving Two Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

My logic is that I want to run the loop while arrA and arrB are not empty. So why would this fail on an input on [a,b,c] and [1,2,3,4]?

```
function combineArrays(arrA, arrB) {
let combined = [];
while (arrA.length != 0 && arrB.length != 0) {
    if (arrA.length != 0) {
        combined.push(arrA.shift());
    }
    if (arrB.length != 0) {
        combined.push(arrB.shift());
    }
}
return combined;
```

Comment: You should use `||` not `&&` in this condition `arrA.length != 0 && arrB.length != 0`

Comment: Read it out loud `while ArrA length is not 0 AND ArrB length is not zero`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `||` not `&&` in this condition `arrA.length != 0 && arrB.length != 0`

```js
function combineArrays(arrA, arrB) {
  let combined = [];
  while (arrA.length != 0 || arrB.length != 0) {
    if (arrA.length != 0) {
      combined.push(arrA.shift());
    }
    if (arrB.length != 0) {
      combined.push(arrB.shift());
    }
  }
  return combined;
}

console.log(combineArrays(['a','b','c'], [1,2,3,4]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will solve with Or operator like below code snippet.

But if you want to concat arrays [Array Concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) can be useful for you.

```js
console.log([1,2,3].concat(["a","b","c"]))
```

```js
function combineArrays(arrA, arrB) {
  let combined = [];
  while (arrA.length != 0 || arrB.length != 0) {
    if (arrA.length != 0) {
      combined.push(arrA.shift());
    }
    if (arrB.length != 0) {
      combined.push(arrB.shift());
    }
  }
  return combined;
}

console.log(combineArrays([1,2,3], ["a","b","c"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

value zero is == false  -->  Boolean(0) === false ( otherwise it's true )

so:

```js
function combineArrays(arrA, arrB)
  {
  let combined = [];
  while (arrA.length || arrB.length)
    {
    if (arrA.length) combined.push(arrA.shift()) 
    if (arrB.length) combined.push(arrB.shift())
    }
  return combined;
}

console.log( combineArrays(['a','b','c'], [1,2,3,4]))
```

You can also do

```js
function combineArrays(arrA, arrB)
  {
  let combined = [], iMax = Math.max(arrA.length,arrB.length)
  for (let i=0; i<iMax; ++i)
    {
    if (i<arrA.length) combined.push(arrA[i]) 
    if (i<arrB.length) combined.push(arrB[i])
    }
  return combined.filter(Boolean)
  }
  
console.log( combineArrays(['a','b','c'], [1,2,3,4]))
```

Or:

```js
function combineArrays(arrA, arrB)
  {
  let combined = [], i = 0;
  for(let a of arrA) { combined[i++] = a; ++i  }
  i=1
  for(let b of arrB) { combined[i++] = b; ++i  }
  return combined.filter(Boolean)
  }

console.log( combineArrays(['a','b','c'], [1,2,3,4]))
```

Or again ( a little bit twisted)

```js
function combineArrays(arrA, arrB)
  {
  let combined = [...arrA,...arrB ]
    , iMin     = Math.min(arrA.length,arrB.length) *2
    , j        = arrA.length
    ;
  for (let i=1; i<iMin; i+=2)
    {
    combined.splice(i,0,combined.splice(j++,1)[0] )
    }
  return combined
  }

console.log( combineArrays(['a','b','c'], [1,2,3,4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

A better apporoach takes the shorter length and iterate the index and remains the given array intact.

```js
function combineArrays(arrA, arrB) {
  let combined = [],
      i = 0,
      l = Math.min(arrA.length, arrB.length);

  while (i < l) {
      combined.push(arrA[i], arrB[i]);
      i++;
  }
  combined.push(...arrA.slice(i), ...arrB.slice(i));
  return combined;
}

console.log(combineArrays(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Answer (score -1):

For 4th iteration arrA.length will be 0, so the while loop will terminate because of AND condition. Use || instead of && in the while loop.